# LESS deployment and build-automation

Tags: deployment, less, build-automation

I've been wanting to get into learning build-automation within web development having only real experience with ANT in building Android applications.

I want to build websites that utilize LESS but I can't see how to achieve this as It sounds like a it's good practice to use the embedded JS approach in development and compile LESS into CSS when deploying but I don't understand a good approach that would match up the LESS links and JS include for jess.js within a build script. e.g.

Replacing:

```
... html ...

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

... html ...
```

With:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="styles.min.css" />
```

I hope what I've mentioned makes sense.

**Useful**

- [HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script)
- [Phing](http://www.phing.info/)

If anyone could give me any pointers/advise on this matter I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the core team for Less.js. Don't use the browser version of LESS if you can avoid it (for instance, you might be enabling users to edit "themes" in real-time in the browser... but  unless you're doing something like that, avoid the browser version).

Try using this build tool for compiling Less to CSS: https://github.com/assemble/assemble-styles. The recommended practice is to pre-compile LESS to CSS, and assemble-styles makes it easy to create "bundles" or multiple versions of your LESS/CSS files, and you can add a watch task so that as you are working on the LESS files they automatically compile to CSS.

With LESS being compiled to CSS as part of the development process, you can then just focus your energy on how you want to handle your CSS in production (without having to even think about LESS). Make sense? If you have any questions I'm happy to help.

If you are familiar with `npm`, then this is simple to use. Just do `npm install assemble-styles`

Then follow the instructions on the README.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've not had any experience with Node and currently don't have any experience with build deployment. I'll look into that link that you recommended and see what I can find out about. Cheers

Comment: No problem, I hope it's useful

Answer (score 1):

No build script will be able to merge a css file with a js file as in your example. They are two completely different languages serving two completely different needs, and they need to be kept apart from each other. As Less is, in the end, just CSS it makes no sense to merge a Less file into a js file.

Moreover best practices suggest to put **css** links in the head of your document (as Steve Souders suggests [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_4/)) and **javascript** code at the end of the document, just before the closing body tag (again Steve Souders, [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)).
If you follow these rules (which is strongly recommended for performance) you'll end up placing css links far away from your js scripts in the html, like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  ....here goes the content of the page

    <script type="text/css" src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, let's imagine a very basic workflow.
You have your bare-bones HTML structure and you need to adjust its layout.
You add a css reset (`reset.css`) and start styling your document in a Less file called `style.less`. If you add

```
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

in the head of your document you won't be able to see any change as browsers do NOT understand .less files. These files need to be pre-processed and "translated" in css, so browsers can parse them and apply the given styles to the HTML page. So you'll run your (.less) file into a preprocessor which in turn will spit out a css file. So your `<head>` will be:

```
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
  <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
```

Notice that the styles.less file will NOT be referenced in the HTML, but only its CSS counterpart styles.css. When you'll be satisfied with your layout it'll be time to move on.

Here's now a good place for a build script to really shine.
A build script will (among other things) concatenate external files of the same kind.
In this case it will be able to merge these two files in a single one. Your new `<head>` will be:

```
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
```

The same thing will happen with js files at the bottom. From:

```
 <script src="one.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="two.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
 <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As I said this is a very basic, rough example of a workflow using Less (or Sass/Scss, or Stylus) and a build script. I would say that Paul Irish gave the simplest and clearest representation of a build script in action in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXpCB3U_4Ig) video, which I highly recommend, especially because it features the HTML5 Boilerplate, as referenced in your question.

Hope this helped you better understanding, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question in such a detailed way and pointing me to some useful resources, namely the build script video. I I think you misunderstood what I wanted to do.. That is find out how others deploy applications and work with LESS. I will update my question to make it clearer.